# Formatting number like 22,55,86,21,28

Tags: javascript

I need to know how i can use javascript to separate a string like 22,44,85,63,12 to individual numbers without the commas e.g.:
22
44
85
63
12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = "one,two,three".split(",") // Delimiter is a string
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    alert(a[i])
}
```

Comment: i ended using it this way:

Comment: function splitter()
 {
  var a = document.getElementById("all_num").value // Delimiter is a string
  var b = a.split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
  {
   //alert(b[i]);
   document.getElementById("res_one").value = b[0];
   document.getElementById("res_two").value = b[1];
   document.getElementById("res_three").value = b[2];
   document.getElementById("res_four").value = b[3];
   document.getElementById("res_five").value = b[4]; 

  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

You need the .split() method like this:

```
var str = "22,44,85,63,12";
var res = str.split(",");
```

res will then be a array of your numbers.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CsyYJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split` and `join` methods

```
var csv = '22,44,85,63,12';
var ssv = csv.split(',').join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

First split the strings -

```
var str = ' 22,44,85,63,12';
var arr = str.split(',');
```

Then create an array of numbers. Check if the element is a number first though.

```
var numberArr = new Array();
var number;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
   number = parseInt(arr[i], 10);
   if(!isNaN(number ))
   {
      numberArray.push(number);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for extracting the array of number-strings, and [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for converting those number-strings to `Number`:

```
var str = "22,44,85,63,12";
var numbers = str.split(",").map(Number);   //[22,44,85,63,12]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the commas with a blank space how about using

```
string.replace(/,/g,' ');
```

but if you want them as separate integers then use `var nums = string.split (",");`

Comment: This would only replace the first occurrence. Check my answer which uses regexp

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
var commaSepStr = "22,44,85,63,12";
var spaceSepStr = commaSepStr.replace(/,/g,' ');
```

This does a global replace. From what i understood, you want the output to be a string and not an array.